# Replacing char to date

Tags: python, excel

I have a dataframe in which one column is of date format type but in some rows, it is written as just SUB instead of date format, how to change it to one particular date(Let us say all SUB be replaced with 28-09-2020) using python?

Comment: Hi Sri, welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's usually best to include in your question what you've tried already and why that didn't work.  That will help others help you more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` and convert error rows to `NaT` then fill those na values with some default values like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"cola": ["10-10-2022", "11-11-2022", "sub"]})
df["cola"] = pd.to_datetime(df["cola"], errors="coerce").fillna("01-01-1976")  # use your default value in fillna
```

Output

```
    cola
0   2022-10-10
1   2022-11-11
2   1976-01-01
```